# Google Chrome стал большой интерфейс после перезагрузки компьютера, как исправить?

Tags: google-chrome

Перезагрузил компьютер, и интерфейс, да и страницы стали отображаться в меньшем разрешении. У меня стоит 1440 x 900. А разрешение браузера - 1132 × 614.
Сбрасывал настройки браузера - не помогло. Повторная перезагрузка тоже. Масштаб 100%.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос решён.**

Это известный баг ещё из 2013 года. 
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=395425
Видимо очередное обновление, принесло старые плоды.

Вроде бы помогло что-то из этого:

```
#1 Modified shortcut to: chrome.exe" /high-dpi-support=1 /force-device-scale-factor=1
#2 Disabled/Enabled DirectWrite on the chrome://flags page.
```